# Angular (ui tree) ng-repeat: infinite loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, infinite-loop, angular-ui-tree

I have a problem with AngularJS and the directive ng-repeat and I can't figure out what's wrong. I'm using angular-ui-tree (https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree) to build an infinite nested tree. The first level of the tree is gonna be build by my code but if I append I child to an existing node the infinite loop error occurs.

So here's my code (I'm sorry but I couldn't get a jsfiddle to run...)

HTML

```
<html ng-app='test'>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="angular-ui-tree.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-ui-tree.min.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type='text/ng-template' id="nodes_renderer.html">
        <div class='tree-node tree-node-content'>
            <button data-nodrag ng-click="toggle(this)" class="btn btn-xs btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></button>
            <span>{{node.title}}</span>
            <button data-nodrag ng-click="upper(this)" ng-disabled="enableBtnUpper(this)" class="btn btn-xs btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></button>
            <button data-nodrag ng-click="lower(this)" ng-disabled="enableBtnLower(this)" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></button>
        </div>
        <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="node.items">
            <li ng-repeat="subItem in node.items" ui-tree-node ng-include="'nodes_renderer.html'"></li>
        </ol>
    </script>
    <div id='tree-root' ui-tree data-no-drag ng-controller='PageStructureController'>
        <ol ui-tree-nodes ng-model='structure'>
            <li ng-repeat='node in structure', ui-tree-node ng-include="'nodes_renderer.html'"></li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my angular controller:

```
angular.module('test', ['ui.tree'])
        .controller('PageStructureController' , ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.structure = [{id:"1", items:[]}];

        $scope.lower = function(scope) {
            var nodeData = scope.$modelValue;
            nodeData.items.push({id: "25", items: []})


        };
        $scope.upper = function(scope) {

        };

        // TODo
        $scope.enableBtnLower = function(scope) {

        }

        $scope.enableBtnUpper = function(scope) {
        };

        $scope.toggle = function (scope) {
        };
    }]);
```

From other questions I've figured out that angular runs through my scope, found a new object -> runs again through my scope -> found a new object and so on.. but I can't figure out where the problem occurs. I know that a new object is created in the lower function but it's the same code like in their examples (https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree/tree/master/examples -> see basic-example)

I hope you can help me :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have an extraneous character `,` after your `ng-repeat="node in structure"`

Second, the issue you're running into is that you are repeating inside your template as `subItem` when the template is expecting scoped repeat items to be accessed as `node`. Changing it to be `ng-repeat="node in node.items"` should fix it.

I took your code and put it into a plunk and made these 2 changes, and it works for me.

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/RPoWoixqWHBr9mD3FuoL?p=preview

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved my problem (also in the whole project).